# Set and validate return value in IF in PHP

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

Could I do this in PHP?

```
if ($Var = $this->test1() == true) {
    var_dump($Var);
}

public function test1() {
    return true;
}
```

It echoes true, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to check such return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can but there is 2 things you should be aware of :

When you do something like :

```
if ($Var = $this->test1() == true) {
```

**The operators are confusing :**

- do you want to do $this->test1() == true and store result $var
- do you want to do $var = $this->test1() and compare it with true

In your case, $this->test1() returns true so it does not matter. But if we change your code a bit :

```
if ($Var = $this->test1() == 5) {
    var_dump($Var);
}

public function test1() {
    return 3;
}
```

Someone who read your code will not understand if you want to store $this->test1() in $Var (so, make 3 in var) or if you want to put result of comparison $this->test1 == 5 in $Var (false).

What remains in $Var at the end may be a very good question at the [PHP 5.3 Certification](http://www.zend.com/services/certification/php-5-certification/) but not in a useful case.

To avoid mistakes, uses parenthesis :

```
if (($var = $this->test1()) == true) {
```

**You should take care of types** :

I give you an example of what could return something castable to true :

```
function test1() { return true; }
function test2() { return 3; }
function test3() { return 3.42; }
function test4() { return "x"; }
function test5() { return array('x'); } // array() == true returns false
function test6() { return new stdClass(); }

echo test1() == true;
echo test2() == true;
echo test3() == true;
echo test4() == true;
echo test5() == true;
echo test6() == true;

// outputs 111111 (1 = true)
```

To avoid mistakes, you should use [=== operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Your final piece of code becomes :

```
if (($var = $this->test1()) === true) {
```

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** you can, but write:

```
if (($var = $this->test1()) === true) {
    var_dump($var);
}
```

To be safe and to alert the reader there is something going on.

I wouldn't advise you to do this though, but in some cases this is acceptable; such as a complex if-else tree where lazy execution is desirable.

```
if (($result = slow_process()) !== false) {
    return $result;
} else if (($result = slow_process1()) !== false) {
    return $result;
} else if (($result = slow_process2()) !== false) {
    return $result;
} else if (($result = slow_process3()) !== false) {
    return $result;
}
```

This is overly simplified, but these situations do occur.

Comment: My function with either return a string or boolean false, would `!== false` be the best way to go?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way, but I wouldn't object to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `== true` part is unnecessary.  What you have is valid syntax, but some find it confusing.  You can always do:

```
$Var = $this->test1();
if ($Var) { ...
```

Just decide on the standard with your development team.

Comment: I'd like to do it in one line, because I'm building quite a "complex" if-else code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
if ($Var = $this->test1()) {
    var_dump($Var);
}

public function test1() {
    return true;
}
```